# GDB: show executed lines for `next [count]` or `step [count]`

Tags: debugging, gdb

When executing `next [count]` or `step [count]` (e.g. `next 10`) in GDB, is there any way to display each line that gets executed, as if you had entered `next` or `step` `[count]` times?

I know that I can execute `next` once and then hold down the enter key for a while, but it's hard to precisely control where to stop when you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gdb doesn't have a built-in way to do this.

You can do it by hand by writing a loop.  This could be done from the CLI by using the `define` command to make a new command, like `verbose-next` that invokes `next` in a loop.  Or, you could write it in Python; though in this case there's no particular advantage to doing so.